# How to retain Timestamp in Camel Bindy, while exporting the POJO to CSV

Tags: apache-camel

Hi I am exporting a POJO to CSV using camel bindy. I have a field which is Timestamp.

```
@DataField(pos=2,pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
private Timestamp createdDate;
```

Now I am getting an error while saving it to CSV, `Can not find a suitable formatter for the type: java.sql.Timestamp`

In documentation i only see pattern for Date. Can someone help me how to retain Timestamp. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

bindy does not support java.sql.Timestamp. Maybe use the java.util.Date instead.